# Embedding a chat in an existing asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, routes, chat

Starting from an existing project (asp.net 4.0 website) where the routing is implemented to make URLs more SEO friendly, I am trying to embed include a project took from here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/562023/Asp-Net-SignalR-Chat-Room

Since I need to write in my global.asax to register the default hubs route: ~/signalr/hubs
I wrote the following code row `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()` as you can see in the code below

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalIR.Owin" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalIR.SystemWeb" %>



<script runat="server">

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'Add an hub route : ~/signalr/hubs
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs()

        ' Code that runs on application startup
        Me.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub

    'Added for redirect and rewriting URL
    Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routeCollection As RouteCollection)


        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteCercaPerTipologia", "find/{type}/", "~/find-type.aspx", False,
End Sub
</script>
```

The issue is on that line of code and the error message is:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Owin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f0ebd12fd5e55cc5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

But as you can see I have got the import at the top of the global.asax file.
I have to say that the project as I mentioned before is using the framework 4.0 but the assembly I am referencing are 4.5 here the paths:

```
\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SignalRChatRoom\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.dll
```

and

```
\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SignalRChatRoom\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.1.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll
```

I tried to delete and reference again the files but nothing worked, is it possible that there is a conflict between the routing that I have implemented and the chat DLLs?

Comment: alternatively if this is not fixable how can I call the chat page from one project to another, I mean I could include the chat project in my solution and I would call the chat page (index.html) contained from chat project, is that possible or just fantasy scenario?